# How to make Two column nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I wanted to have two column nomenclature. So far I have the following code that I am working on that. Is there any idea how should I make them in two column? I also want to remove the printing date below the nomenclature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This will add the subgroups
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Number Sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%----------------------------------------------

%% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------

\title{Nomenclatures}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\mbox{}

\nomenclature[A, 01]{$\dot\rho$}{D}
\nomenclature[A, 02]{$\bf \nabla$}{N}
\nomenclature[A, 03]{$\mathcal{R}$}{R}
\nomenclature[A, 04]{$\sigma$}{DS}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the two hooks `\nompreamble` and `\nompostamble`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This will add the subgroups
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Number Sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%----------------------------------------------

%% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}

\title{Nomenclatures}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\mbox{}

\nomenclature[A, 01]{$\dot\rho$}{D}
\nomenclature[A, 02]{$\bf \nabla$}{N}
\nomenclature[A, 03]{$\mathcal{R}$}{R}
\nomenclature[A, 04]{$\sigma$}{DS}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just add `\usepackage{multicol}` to your preamble and then:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnomenclature
\end{multicols}
```

I don't understand the issue with the date.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the heading of the nomenclature is also part of the two column environment and hence it doesn't look as I expect it. I therefore prefer the solution of @egreg