# Two column nomenclature with title above the columns

Tags: multicol, nomenclature, nomencl

I'd like to print a nomenclature in two columns while keeping the title outside (above) the columns, starting from this:

[image: starting_point]

I used `multicols` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321392/how-to-make-two-column-nomenclature), but it includes the title in the first column.

[image: title]

Using `\renewcommand{\nomname}{}` creates a blank line in the first column.

[image: blank]

Removing `\renewcommand{\nomname}{}` prints **Nomenclature** as the default title (so it looks like the second picture again).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\title{Nomenclature}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\mbox{}
\nomenclature{Spa.}{Spanish}
\nomenclature{Lat.}{Latin}
\nomenclature{It.}{Italian}
\nomenclature{Fr.}{French}
\nomenclature{En.}{English}
\nomenclature{Pt.}{Portuguese}
\nomenclature{Rus.}{Russian}
\nomenclature{Ger.}{German}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnomenclature
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And this is my goal:

[image: goal]

(I found [this possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357801/nomenclature-in-2-columns) but nothing appears when I compile the suggested code.)

Answer (score 2):

nomencl package has a preamble and a postamble to add code before and after the list, so the adjustement is rather simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % unnecessary in modern LaTeX
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}

\title{Nomenclature}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nomenclature{Spa.}{Spanish} \nomenclature{Lat.}{Latin}
\nomenclature{It.}{Italian}  \nomenclature{Fr.}{French}
\nomenclature{En.}{English}  \nomenclature{Pt.}{Portuguese}
\nomenclature{Rus.}{Russian} \nomenclature{Ger.}{German}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

This then gives

[image]